# How to describe the traveling salesman problem with an integer programming model?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, network-flow

I'm trying to describe the travelling salesman problem as an integer programming model. I'm interested in the asymmetric version of the problem. The problem can be summarized as finding the optimal Hamilton circuit. We also always start at node 1. ex: 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 3 -> 1 is a solution for a graph containing 4 nodes.

I have the following constraints :

(1) $\sum_{(i,j) \in A^+} y_{ij} = 1$ Here $y_{ij}$ is a binary variable. if it's equal to 1 it means that the edge $(i,j)$ is in the optimal path. $(i,j) \in A^+$ means all edges that enters in a node $A$.

(2) $\sum_{(j,i) \in A^-} y_{ji} = 1$ Same thing but with every edge that exits a node $A$.

In the following constraints we use $x_{ij} \geq 0$ which represents the flow on an edge $(i,j)$

(3) $\sum_{(i,j) \in A^+(i)} x_{ij} = |V|$ when $i \in V \text{ , } i = 1$ This means that the total flow that exit through the various edges going out of node 1 is equal to the number of nodes in the graph.

(4) $\sum_{(i,j) \in A^+(i)} x_{ij} - \sum_{(j,i) \in A^-(i)} x_{ji} = -1$ when $i \in V \text{ , } i \neq 1$ This means that a node i consume one unit of flow. The exception is node 1.

(5) $\sum_{(j,i) \in A^-(i)} x_{ji} = 1$ when $i \in V \text{ , } i = 1$ This means that the flow that is sent to node 1 is equal to 1. This correspond to when we arrive to our destination ex: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1.

This programming model is not complete as long as I do not link the binary variables with the flow variables. However I don't understand how to do it properly. Should a new constraint be added?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To enforce $x_{i,j} > 0 \implies y_{i,j} = 1$, you can impose a linear big-M constraint $$x_{i,j} \le (|V|-1) y_{i,j}.$$

This TSP formulation is described in Application 16.2 of Ahuja, Magnanti, and Orlin, *Network Flows*.

Comment: For the first node should the big-M constraint be $x_{1,j} \leq |V| y_{1,j}$? Imagine we have 4 nodes this means that node 1 will send 4 units of flow on one of its edges to node ex: 2. Node 2 will consume 1 unit and send 3 units to the next node. It's only when we arrive back at node 1 that it will consume 1 unit.

Comment: That's what I had at first, but you need not send 1 unit back to node 1.  Ahuja uses $|V|-1$.

Comment: Could you tell me where I can find the big-M constraint in 16.2? I don't see it, maybe I'm not looking at the right edition of the book?

Comment: In my copy, it is (16.3e): $x_{i,j} \le (n-1)y_{i,j}$.  The big-M value is $n-1$, which corresponds to your $|V|-1$.

Comment: I have edited the question. I need a third constraint and the constraint given in your answer doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In Ahuja's formulation, your constraint (3) is instead $=|V|-1$ and your constraint (5) is omitted.  The "third constraint" that you describe needing is your constraint (4).  The idea is to send one unit of flow from node 1 to each of the other $|V|-1$ nodes.

Comment: But that wouldn't make a hamilton cycle? I need to send the from the first node to the second node 4 units and from the second to the third 3 units and so on.

Comment: The $y$ variables and constraints (1) and (2) enforce a union of cycles.  The $x$ variables and flow constraints enforce connectivity so that there is only one cycle in the union.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused. So the third constraint I need is $x_{i,j} \leq (|V| - 1)y_{i,j}$ for every edge that does not come out or enter in node 1? Am I getting this right?

Comment: That constraint should be imposed for all edges.

Comment: The problem is that I have to solve this integer programming using three constraints that I described in my edit of the question. They may be other ways to solve this by just applying one constraint but I'm imposed to have three constraints where the third one must capture what happens to edges that are not going in or out of node 1. Do you know how I could possibly find this constraint? I'm having a hard time with that.'